# Python try to make unmovable tic tac toe board

Tags: python

my problem is when a board is fulfill it will look ugly.

this is when board not fulfill.

```
def board_tictactoe(board):
    print('-----------------------------------------------------')
    print('|         ' + '       |        ' + '         |        ' + '        |')
    print('|         ' + board[7] + '       |       ' + board[8] + '          |         ' + board[9] + '       |')
    print('|         ' + '       |        ' + '         |          ' + '      |')
    print('-----------------------------------------------------')
    print('|         ' + '       |        ' + '         |        ' + '        |')
    print('|         ' + board[4] + '       |       ' + board[5] + '          |         ' + board[6] + '       |')
    print('|         ' + '       |        ' + '         |          ' + '      |')
    print('------------------------------------------------------')
    print('|         ' + '       |        ' + '         |        ' + '        |')
    print('|         ' + board[1] + '       |       ' + board[2] + '          |         ' + board[3] + '       |')
    print('|         ' + '       |        ' + '         |          ' + '      |')
    print('------------------------------------------------------')

board = ['','','','','','','','','','']
```

OUTPUT
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgBvm.jpg)

and when board is fulfill

```
board = ['','','X','','O','','','X','','']
```

OUTPUT
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3mFr.jpg)

I want to make a board that wont move when there are a text or not, i want to make sudoku board too but i stuck on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) and [string formatting](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp).

Here's a sample (I cleaned it up a little too)

```
empty_line = "|                |                |                |"
horizontal_line = "-----------------------------------------------------"
print(horizontal_line)
print(empty_line)
print(f"|{board[7]:^16}|{board[8]:^16}|{board[9]:^16}|")
print(empty_line)
print(horizontal_line)
```

`f"{var:^16}"` Tells python to make print `var` out such that it's center aligned within 16 characters (and the default fill character is a space).

If this answers your question dont forget to click the check.

Comment: thanks you so much. where to click check i cant found it

Comment: Its right under the up and down arrows on the left.